# Selection of only monthly data on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can you suggest an approach to select January Landsat 5 data between 2000 to 2010 and calculate its mean?

In other words, the mean of the all January images from 2000 to 2010.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You nee to use `ee.Filter.calendarRange(start,end,field)` to filter by all Januaries from 2000 to 2010.

`field` could be:

> - field (String, default: "day_of_year"): The calendar field to filter
>     over. Options are: 'year', 'month', 'hour', 'minute', 'day_of_year',
>     'day_of_month', and 'day_of_week'.

So, the code is:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA");

// Use ee.Filter.calendarRange to filter by year and month

var img = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000,2010,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));

// reduce image collection with mean()
var mean = img.mean();

// Set visualization parameters
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.5,
  gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};

// add layer
Map.addLayer(mean,vizParams);
```

This code process specifically your task description, doesn't consider cloud mask or a cloud coverage filter.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable answer. Thanks a lot, but i have a question here,
var img = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000,2010,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));

It is taking only January 2000 and January 2010,

Comment: var img = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000,2010,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));

It is filtering all images from January 2000 to January2010. I need only january from every year.

Thank you

Comment: @P_P weird, I test it and takes every year. Try with `.filterDate(“2000-01-01” , “2010-01-31”)` instead of first filter.

Comment: Thank You for your kind reply. I started with this  .filterDate(“2000-01-01” , “2010-01-31”) but its is taking all images between these dates.

Comment: @P_P yes, but I said as remplace of first filter (year filter), you need to keep the second filter (month filter).