# Writing code for monthly NDVI medians in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: landsat, google-earth-engine, ndvi

My goal is to get monthly NDVI medians in Google Earth Engine. This helpful post got me started: [reduce image collection to get annual monthly sum precipitation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258344/reduce-image-collection-to-get-annual-monthly-sum-precipitation)

However, I am using Landsat (not MODIS). This script does run but the map layer has "no bands to visualize".

1. How can I visualize the bands? (Maybe the issue is that this dataset only has 1 band?).
2. How can I add all 12 map layers, one per month? (perhaps with stacking?)

```js
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_32DAY_NDVI');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

// Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// month.
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  months.map(function (m) {
    return ndvi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                .select().median()
                .set('month', m);
}));
print(byMonth);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()));
```

Comment: Try removing the instance `.select()` inside the `map`. This function is used to selects bands from an image and it was empty. I tried it and it seems to work. Be aware that you are making multi-annual monthly medians this way (but maybe that was the point).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (your title and your question do not match), but here is a script I put together for doing this at the annual resolution: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ecbddc2c2a191c12d6bd16dfab164452 You'll notice there's a bit of masking--for water, and for edges of scenes where there's invalid data.

Comment: @Kamo: thanks! that did it. Perhaps I wasn't clear, but yes, multi-annual monthly medians are exactly what I was after. I am still not sure how to look at the month-by-month results (something in that last command)

Comment: @Jon: that is a great script; I like how you filter the dates and use multiple Landsat datasets based on year. Very useful

Answer (score 14):

For the record, here is a good way to do this:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1");
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var composites = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(months.map(function(m) {
  var filtered = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: m,
    field: 'month'
  }));
  var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(filtered);
  return composite.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI')
      .set('month', m);
}));
print(composites);

var check = ee.Image(composites.first());
Map.addLayer(check, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'check');
```

For the search robots, this is a "temporally grouped reduction."

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to get multi-annual monthly (and seasonal) NDVI medians. It's based on this useful post: [Selection of only monthly data on Google earth engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256297/selection-of-only-monthly-data-on-google-earth-engine?rq=1)

The code is not elegant but it gets the job done (I define variables for each month and season instead of looping through them). Hopefully it's useful!
https://code.earthengine.google.com/cc2e0f6c4f67885405236024abea0d86

Comment: I would NOT use those NDVI composites.  They are full of clouds.

Comment: Yes, but they have great resolution (30m). I chose a median (instead of a mean) because it's not affected by outliers such as cloudy or NoData pixels. Each monthly median has 28 data points (one per year), which seems like enough to arrive at a stable median. I also tried it with 8-day averages, which is much slower, but significantly increases the sample size.