# Google Earth Engine: How to calculate regular day interval means in image collections, maintaining "system:time.start" field?

Tags: landsat, modis, google-earth-engine, spatio-temporal-data

I've merged three Landsat collections in Google Earth Engine, now I need to calculate median values at regular time intervals, let's say 32 days, because I will create a collection to join with MODIS. However, when I do that, I lose the "system:time.start" information from Landsat Merged collections. Does anyone knows how to calculate this regular medians based on DOY? **I want to filter the Landsat_merge collection to 32 days regular interval**!

This is the code so far: 
[Code to access MODIS Landsat Joined collections](https://code.earthengine.google.com/45cc274ee09324fed1f8267e7d0c5b40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet to get you started, based on code in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-earth/making-it-easier-to-reuse-code-with-earth-engine-script-modules-2e93f49abb13):

```
var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units) {
  // Create a sequence of numbers, one for each time interval.
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));

  var originalStartDate = ee.Date(start);

  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i) {
    // Get the start date of the current sequence.
    var startDate = originalStartDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);

    // Get the end date of the current sequence.
    var endDate = originalStartDate.advance(
      ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);

    return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).median()
        .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
        .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
  }));
};

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA');

var result = temporalCollection(landsat8, '2016-01-01', 12, 32, 'day');

var first = ee.Image(result.first());
Map.addLayer(first, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3}, 'first');
```

Note that another variant of this is described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279789/96644).